# Как средствами Ajax получить отображение страницы по запросу GET?

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

Имеется скрипт для отправки запроса GET:

```
$.ajax({
url:'/accounts/' + id,
type:'GET',
success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
    if(data) {
        console.log('Success');
    }
    else {
        console.log('No data received from server');
    }
},
error: function(){
    alert('It was not possible to connect the server');
}

});
```

Скрипт выполняется успешно и в виде `data` получает html файл с кодом запрашиваемой страницы. Текст данного файла выводится в консоли, но как его можно отобразить в виде страницы? Можно было бы, конечно, просто сделать переход на нужную страницу `top.location.href = 'accounts/' + id`. Но дело в том, что здесь представлен упрощенный вариант скрипта. На самом деле, запрос `GET` должен
отправляться с параметрами, которые идентифицируют пользователя с указанным id (логин и пароль). Если отправлять их в строке `top.location.href = 'accounts/' + id`, то они будут отображаться в адресной строке браузера.

Comment: если я Вас правильно понял то Вы хотите вывести результат `ajax` запроса на той же странице в определенном блоке?

Comment: Нет, поместить полученный ответ в div на той же странице получается, но хотелось бы показать полученную страницу в отдельном окне.

Comment: а почему тогда не переадресовать на нужную страницу?

Comment: Ну там ситуация пока нерешенная. Надо переадресовывать на страницу пользователя, которая должна получать логин и пароль, и если переадресовывать, то надо их указывать через параметры и они тогда видны в браузере.

Comment: А передавать параметры через POST в чем проблема?

Comment: Ну там проблема в том, что на бэк-энде используется фреймворк Restlet, в котором каждый из запросов GET, POST и PUT определен с учетом конкретных действий - GET для получения данных, POST для добавления нового пользователя, а PUT - для редактирования. Таким образом, POST как бы занят.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел, возможно и не самый лучший вариант со всплывающей страницей:

```
var newWin = window.open("about:blank", "hello", "width=500,height=700");
newWin.document.write(data);
```

Хотя, всплывающие страницы браузер обычно блокирует...